# Make a hyperlink from SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have several "providers" with website urls listed in a table. I am wondering how I would link their websites that are listed in the table to make them live urls.

```
<?php if($Website){
  echo "<div class='providerData1'>Website: </div> <div class='providerData1 providerData2'>" . $Website .  "</div><br />"; }
?>
```

Any ideas? Thank you. :)

Comment: Does `$Website` contain the URL? If so, just wrap it in an anchor tag...

Comment: It does, a url for each provider in the database.

Comment: You could use a `while` (or `foreach`) loop along with `mysqli_fetch_array()` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and do something like `$site = $row['link']; echo "Page: <a href='$site'>$site</a><br>";`

Comment: so it would be this?

mysqli_fetch_array() 
echo $Website = $row['link']; echo "Page: <a href='$Website'>$Website</a><br>"; }

Comment: More like `$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select link....); while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ $site = $row['link']; echo "Page: <a href='$site'>$site</a><br>"; }` yet, there are other ways of achieving this.

Comment: I can post a piece of code as an answer if you want to have a look. @user3466094 You'll need to fill in your own info though.

Answer (score 0):

Base yourself on the following: (details can be found in comments)

```
<?php

$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";

$db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect [' . $db->connect_errno . ']');
}

// Use
// $sql = mysqli_query($db, "select * from tablename ");
// Or select particular columns
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "select link,name from tablename LIMIT 1");
// You can remove LIMIT 1 if you want to show them all

    echo "Pages (found):";
    echo "<hr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

    $name= $row['name'];
    $Website = $row['link'];

    echo $name;
    echo "<br>";

    echo "<div class='providerData1'>Website: </div> <div class='providerData1 providerData2'><a href='$Website'>" . $name .  "</a></div><br />";

    }

    echo "<br>";

?>
```

---

In place of the entire `while` loop, you can replace it with:

Sidenote (having a URL for the `link` column)

```
echo '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Page</th><th>Link</th></tr>';
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  echo '<tr><td>'.$row["name"].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row["link"].'</td>';
  echo '<td><a href="'.$row["link"].'">Link</a></td></tr>';

}
echo '</table>';
```

and display your links neatly in an HTML table.

Comment: Thank you. What part to I enter the field $website in?

Comment: You're welcome. I made an edit with your div stuff in there. Reload to see the changes. @user3466094 You'll need to play around with it to your liking, but you get the general idea.

Comment: If you want to show all links, simply remove `LIMIT 1` @user3466094 or to limit to 3 links, use `LIMIT 3`